# how to display a validation list with value from two columns of another tab?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a requirement where i need to apply a list validation in such a way that list should display data from two columns (of different tab in same excel) combined with "-" ?
I am able to display the single column using named range but unable to display with two columns?
[image: First tab which has source columns]

[image: Second Tab which should list combined columns]

How can we achieve this?

Below is the problem with helper column.For new record, i do not have values in helper column.Hence, list doesn't display the new records.

[image: Problem with helper column]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want to concatenate values in columns B and C and display the concatenated value in the validation list?

Comment: @AHC : Yes. Combine B and C with "-" and display it in list.

Comment: why don't you use a helper column? concatenate them in a separate column and pull the new values from that column?

Comment: Use-case here is that data is exported to excel and make the changes to the excel and import is back to system. So, when i export, i can have the Column C (Hidden) with value combined and i can use it in list in another tab. But for new rows which are inserted in source tab corresponding values will not be available in column C. Therefore, i cannot see the values newly inserted in list. Hope i am clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so basically you need a bit of roundabout:
you can [download the example sheet here to follow the steps.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zu00223nvbjktw4/data%20validation_blanks.xlsx?dl=0)

here is the screenshot:
[image]
***First:***
use a **helper column C**, and concatenate the values in **A** and **B** using the following formyla:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2:B999),"",CONCATENATE(A2," - ",B2))
```

drag and fill down until any cell you want, in the example i did until cell **C99**, where your cells in column B are empty, you will get a blank cell in column **C**. 
***Second:***

Create a *name* in the **name manager** (I named it *TrimmedList* in this example) and ask it to refer to the following formula, copy and paste it in the **refers to**:

```
=Example!$C$2:INDEX(Example!$C$2:$C$99;COUNTIF(Example!$C$2:$C$99;"?*"))
```

by the way, my sheet's name is *Example*.

 then press OK and close the name manager.

***Third:***

Select **E2:E100** and click on data validation, then allow for **LIST** and copy and paste the following in the source, then click OK:

```
=TrimmedList
```

as you remember our **name** was named *TrimmedList*.

there you go! you can manually add new entries and try the drop down menu! you will only see the values and not the blanks.

Comment: The solution is correct. However, in my case i cannot add any new column to the source tab ( When new values are added to the B and C it will not be available in column C and also in list).
Also, in my case the list is used in separate tab.

Comment: @Nikhil: what do you mean by not available in column C?

Comment: Use-case here is that data is exported to excel and make the changes to the excel and import is back to system. So, when i export, i can have the Column C (Hidden) with value combined and i can use it in list in another tab. But for new rows which are inserted in source tab corresponding values will not be available in column C. Therefore, i cannot see the values newly inserted in list.  Hope i am clear!

Comment: @Nikhil: sorry, i don't get the point. provide an example sheet if you like.

Comment: I have modified the question to include the problem with helper column.

Comment: @Nikhil: i modified my answer completely. tell me if your problem is solved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74563/discussion-between-nikhil-and-ahc).